# Jquery/Draggable/Background window to the foreground with a mouse click /How?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I use the stack option to get the background windows to the the foreground by dragging. But I am stacked
when I want to get a window in the foreground by clicking. I couldn't figure out how to get the largest z-index.

EDIT:

```
$('.drag').draggable({stack: '.drag'}
```

This code brings the background `div.drag` in the foreground, but just if you drag it. I want the background `div.drag` to get into the foreground also when you click it. If you just click it it stays int the background.

EDIT 2:

Meanwhile I used:

```
var zIndex = $('.drag').length;
$('.drag').draggable({stack: '.drag'},
    stop: function() {
        zIndex = $(this).css('z-index');
    }
}).click(function(event){
    $(this).css('z-index', ++zIndex);
});
```

Comment: I can't understand your question.  For a better response you may want to rewrite it and show some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this the [same way jQueryUI does](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/58b730f7c7a2fa848eeab12c5b26736a102ed1a4/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js#L766) (unfortunately I couldn't figure out a way to manually trigger this method):

```
$(".drag").draggable({
    stack: ".drag"
}).bind("click", function() {
    var o = $(this).data("draggable").options;
    var group = $.makeArray($(o.stack)).sort(function(a, b) {
        return (parseInt($(a).css("zIndex"), 10) || 0) - (parseInt($(b).css("zIndex"), 10) || 0);
    });

    if (!group.length) {
        return;
    }

    var min = parseInt(group[0].style.zIndex) || 0;
    $(group).each(function(i) {
        this.style.zIndex = min + i;
    });

    this.style.zIndex = min + group.length;
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/uYpnW/2/

Hope that helps!